# Restrict communication between client application and WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Because of the security concerns, I want my client application(written in asp.net) can only consume the exposed methods of its service(built in WCF) and no other client application may able to consume the methods exposed by service.

I do have UserName and Password based authentication implemented, does it require authorization by issuing any kind of token or certificate?

Please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Beautiful example of using WCF transport security and client certificate authentication.

http://robbincremers.me/2011/12/27/wcf-transport-security-and-client-certificate-authentication-with-self-signed-certificates/

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link , I already have self-signed certificate and it is server certificate which exist in Trusted People authorities. Is this sufficient according to my requirement?

Comment: Is there any other way because I am using UserName Authentication and in webconfig, clientCredentialType node value is UserName and I can't change this any how. So is there any other way to authenticate client while it reaches to service.